# Android error query SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I have a query like this:

```
String sql ="SELECT _id, field10, field11, SUM(field2) FROM Table WHERE field2>0 AND data LIKE '"+anno+"-%'";
```

If in the database, it is stored a string like this (pubblicita') I get syntax error like this:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "2014": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
 SELECT _id, field10, field11, SUM(field2) FROM Table WHERE field2>0 AND field10 LIKE 'PUBBLICITA'' AND data LIKE '2014-%'
```

The problem lies in the apex, how can I solve this case?

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately, all the answers are wrong. The error is generated if the string corresponding with the apex. See the image 
[image]

Comment: Is your variable `anno` integer ?

Comment: Note that this is not the query that causes this error and all the answers are attempting to fix the wrong problem.

Comment: See my new answer. Thanks. The variable `anno` is integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL string literals, quotes must be escaped by doubling them.

However, you can avoid doing this manually by passing the string as a [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```java
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ... data LIKE ? || '-%'",
                     new String[] { anno });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape quote character before using string in sql.

```
public static String escapeSQLQuotes(final String in) {
    return in.replaceAll("'", "''");
}
```

and use:

```
String sql ="SELECT _id, field10, field11, SUM(field2) FROM Table WHERE field2>0 AND data LIKE '"+escapeSQLQuotes(anno)+"-%'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
String sql ="SELECT _id, field10, field11, SUM(field2) FROM Table WHERE field2>0 AND data LIKE '"+anno+"%'";

"-%'" replace "%'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `"-%"` with `"%"`

```
String sql ="SELECT _id, field10, field11, SUM(field2) FROM Table WHERE field2>0 AND data*  LIKE '"+anno+"%'";
```